# why hover doesn't work .CSS RGBA NOT WORKING

Tags: css, hover, opacity, rgba

why rgba hover does not work ?
this my code

```
.img {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background: url(http://cos.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

not working rgba

```
.image:hover{
background-color: rgba(251, 181, 59, 0.5);
```

Comment: do you close the image class? like so, .image:hover{
background-color: rgba(251, 181, 59, 0.5); }

Comment: Yes of course close the image class,

Comment: You are clear that your basic element class is called .img and your hover is on the .image?

Comment: my hover is on the image

Comment: @dejwwis try my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are not closed image style properly. Check your code once. Meanwhile try my example, here Image hover works fine, i just gave some border for better understanding, may be this will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.main{
padding:20px;
margin:20px;
}
.img {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif") no-repeat;
padding:20px;
margin:20px;
}
.img:hover{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
border:5px solid green;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="main">
 <div class="img"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```